# PHP - Count amount of rows joined

Tags: php

I'm having the following code:

I wan't to count how many Answers there is to a specific Thread/lookup. Like, how many replied to this lookup.

```
function lookup()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM lookup
            INNER JOIN lookupCategories
            ON lookup.FK_lookupCategory=lookupCategories.lookupCategoriesId
            INNER JOIN lookupType
            ON lookup.FK_lookupType=lookupType.lookupTypeId
            LEFT JOIN authentication
            ON lookup.FK_lookupUserId=authentication.userId
            LEFT JOIN freelanceTypes
            ON lookup.FK_freelanceTypes=freelanceTypes.freelanceTypesId
            LEFT JOIN lookupAnswer
            ON lookup.lookupId=lookupAnswer.FK_lookupId
            ORDER BY lookupId DESC
            LIMIT 5";
    $result = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());

    $viewLookup = Array();

    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)):

        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupId'] = $row['lookupId'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupHeader'] = $row['lookupHeader'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupSubHeader'] = $row['lookupSubHeader'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupContent'] = $row['lookupContent'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupDate'] = $row['lookupDate'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupCategory'] = $row['lookupCategoryName'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupType'] = $row['lookupTypeName'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupByUsername'] = $row['username'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupByUserId'] = $row['userId'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['lookupFreelanceTypeId'] = $row['FK_freelanceTypes'];
        $viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['freelanceWinner'] = $row['freelanceWinner'];

    endwhile;
    return $viewLookup;
}
```

And I wan't to count the amount of 'answers' to a thread. My threads are joined to the lookup's. And afterwards stored in an array as you see.

How would I count the answers, and store the number in the array together with the rest of my data? I have tried to do this, but can't figure out what's wrong. It's just returning if there's something or not - 1 or NULL.

```
$viewLookup[$row['lookupId']]['countAnswers'] = count($row['lookupAnswerId']);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Is `$row['lookupAnswerId']` an array? If not, `count` won't work.

Comment: No, $row['lookupAnswerId'] is just a row from the answers table. I think this is my problem, but I can't figure out what to do then.

Comment: Are you looking for just the number of rows returned from the table?  If so, you're looking for mysql_num_rows (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: No, I am not. I wan't to count the answers connected to the Lookup's. I've joined the answers. How do I count something which is joined? If it's even possible. I know about mysql_num_rows.

Comment: So you want to count how many entries have the same 'lookupAnswerId' ?

Comment: @John No, I wan't to count how many Answers there is for a specific Thread. I think my question is a bit misleading.

Comment: @Kolind  don't limit your query to five while make many joins

Comment: @SamArulRaj Why not? I'm using data from the joins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = select count(*)....
```

Rest add the conditions.

Comment: so you wan't me to do following: select count(*) from lookup... and then join the rest, or what?

Comment: Do the 1st query as you wrote. To get the number, do the 2nd query just changing the count(*), rest same and it'l return the number. Alternately, you can also use $number = mysql_num_rows($result) where $result is the mysql resource (the one you recieve after the query).

Comment: I can't do this, since I can't count after an id, since I have to show how many answers there is for a specific thread on a frontpage. I could've done this if I had an id to count after.

Comment: Then make another query with thread id in the WHERE clause. It'l return all the data plus number of answers on that thread.